# Storing Location coordinates in Database(mysql)

Tags: javascript, php, maps

Hello Guys I am facing Problem in Getting The User location coordinates in my PHP code to Insert it into my Database.....

I have tried a lot of ways ,Using DOM and other but no one worked....
I was Able to Print coordinates or JSON.stringify returned String on Browser but couldn't Updated it in database.....
and the following PHP Script return an Error is...
ERROR::::Notice: Undefined index: coords in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\PRoject\php\Show.php on line 69
NULL

Please Help,my Code is below

//PHP

```
$coords=$_POST['coords'];

$decode= json_decode($coords,true);
var_dump($decode);


$query="UPDATE `coords` SET `coords`='$decode' WHERE 
        `driver`.`id`='$uid'";
mysqli_query($conn,$query);
```

//Javascript

```
  function initMap() {
    var x=navigator.geolocation;
  x.getCurrentPosition(success,failure);
  function success(pos){

  var y=pos.coords.latitude;
  var z=pos.coords.longitude;
    var coords= {lat:y,lng:z};

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: coords,
      zoom: 8

    });
    var marker= new google.maps.Marker({
      position:coords,
      map:map,
    title:'my pos'
    });
    console.log(coords);
    var str=JSON.stringify(coords);
    console.log(str);
    $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
        url:'Show.php',
        data:{coords:str},
        success:function(str){
            alert(str);
        }
    });

  }
```

Comment: It seems that $_POST['coords'] does not exist.  Perhaps try $_REQUEST['coords'].

Comment: Thanks, but it's resulting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I was sending the post request to the same page means my php and js scripts were in same page. So I then send that post data to another page and it worked.
Cheers